# $f:(X,S) \to R$ be a measurable function , does $\{f^{-1}((-\infty,x]): x \in \mathbb R\}$ generate $\{f^{-1}(A):A \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R)\}$?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $S$ be a $\sigma$-algebra over $X$ , let $\mathcal B (\mathbb R)$ be the Borel sigma algebra over the real line , let

$f:(X,S) \to (\mathbb R, \mathcal B (\mathbb R))$ be a measurable function , then trivially $G :=\{f^{-1}(A):A \in \mathcal B (\mathbb R)\}$ is a

sigma algebra and $H:=\{f^{-1}((-\infty,x]): x \in \mathbb R\}$ is a pi-system over $X$ , my question is , is it

true that $\sigma (H)=G$ ?

Comment: By $\sigma(H)$ do you mean the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $H$?

Comment: @YotasTrejos : yes that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1):

From countable union and complements of elements in $H$ you may get every set of the form $f^{-1}((a,b))$ where $a<b\in \mathbb{R}$ then $\sigma(H)$ contains every set with of this form. The $\sigma$-algebra $G$ is generated by those sets, then $G\subset \sigma(H)$ but since $H\subset G$ then $\sigma(H)\subset G$. Therefore $G=\sigma(H)$.